# Sequelize optional where clause parameters?

Tags: sequelize.js

This is one thing that really annoys me! I have to write 2 different functions for almost the same query!

Say I've got an API that returns `posts` that are associated to a particular `typeId` and `cityId`. To get `ALL` posts that are associated to `typeId 1 OR 2, OR 3` ***and*** `cityId 1` I would parse the following to my sequelize `findAll` query:

```
$or: [{typeId: 1}, {typeId: 2}, {typeId: 3}]
cityId: 1
```

But say I want to get all post where `cityId = 1 andOr typeId = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,etc...` I cannot do something like:

```
var types = [{typeId: 1}, {typeId: 2}, {typeId: 3}]
Post.findAll({
     where: {
          if (types != []) $or: types,
          cityId: 1
      }
```

So instead I have to make a new query that won't include the `$or: types` where clause...Because if I parse an empty `types` array I get a weird `sql` output:

```
WHERE 0 = 1 AND `post`.`cityId` = '1'
```

Notice how it's outputting 0 = 1?! No idea why

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could build the where object beforehand. Here's a simple example

```js
// Get typeIds from whatever source you have

// Here's an example
var typeIds = [1, 2, 3];

// Or you could try this to build a query without typeIds
// var typeIds = [];

var whereCondition = {};

if (typeIds.length > 0) {
    whereCondition['$or'] = typeIds.map(function(id) {
        return {
            typeId: id
        };
    })
};

whereCondition['cityId'] = 1;

console.log(whereCondition);

Post.findAll(whereCondition).then(function(posts) {
    // The rest of your logic
});
```

Comment: This is the perfect solution. Can't believe I didn't think of it earlier!

Comment: the perfect solution is using a where property key with as value undefined, which doesn't work (this is a bug in sequelize)

Answer (score 5):

You can do this:

```
Post.findAll({
     where: {
          cityId: 1,
          ...(types && types.length && {
              types
          })
      }
```

`types` attr will only be evaluated in the expression if the array has elements.

Answer (score 0):

i had some similar situation , and i used template literals to define empty string as default if the field was undefined.

```
User.findOne({
where: {
  [Op.or]: [
    { email: `${req.body.email || ""}` },
    { username: `${req.body.username || ""}` },
  ],
},
```

})

Answer (score 0):

I discovered a handy trick a while back that I'd like to share. This trick is particularly useful when you have multiple parameters (like name, age, gender, phone number, account number, date of birth, etc.) that are all optional. That is, the user can provide either all parameters or just one. I found using 'if-else' statements to handle this scenario was not scalable. So, here's an alternative approach you can consider:

```
let name = req.body.name ? { name: req.body.name } : undefined;
let gender = req.body.gender ? { gender: req.body.gender } : undefined;
let phoneNumber = req.body.phoneNumber ? { phoneNumber: req.body.phoneNumber } : undefined;

let users = await User.findAll({
   where: {
      [Op.and]: [
         name,
         gender,
         phoneNumber
      ]
   }
})
```

this will work only with Op operator such as and , I am not sure about other operators. Please let me know if you have questions on this.

Comment: my blog if you want to read extra few sentence : [blog](https://manojmula.github.io/portfolio/read-blog/sequelizeOptionalParameters/programming)