# Sequelize Remove "where" if query isn't provided?

Tags: sequelize.js

So I'm basically passing some query strings to my endpoint to use as filters, and I'm using Sequelize.

I know I can use `where` to filter/find records, but I want to make it so that if I don't provide a query string, it just gets ignored.

Current:

```
const { status } = req.query;

const tickets = await models.Ticket.findAndCountAll({
  where: {
    status,
  },
  attributes: [
    'id',
    'status'
  ],
});
```

If I don't pass status as a query string, it fails since `where` can't execute. I tried also passing `undefined` to it but no luck, it errors out saying;
`ERROR: WHERE parameter "status" has invalid "undefined" value`

So to summarise, I want to make it so that if I do provide the query strings, they are inserted into the `where` clause, but if they aren't, then it's just ignored.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36466395/sequelize-optional-where-clause-parameters

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's simply a case of only including the `where` options if you know `status` has a value Sequelize can use.

```
const { status } = req.query;

// declare our query options
const options = {
    where: {},
    attributes: [
        'id',
        'status'
    ]
};

// if status has a value (!== undefined), include it in the query
if (status !== undefined)
    options.where.status = status;

const tickets = await models.Ticket.findAndCountAll(options);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. It is very obvious but for some reason not that apparent to hit one's mind in the first try on it's own