# Optional parameters on sequelize query

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

Good morning.

I'm quite new to NodeJS / sequelize world and I'm currently facing a problem while trying to display a dashboard on screen.

This dashboard has three filters: two dates (period), client name, and employee name. The user can select none, one, two, or all the filters and my database needs to work accordingly.

That being said, my problem is with Sequelize because I don't know how to treat this problem of parameters not being "always" there.

I've seen this question:

[Sequelize optional where clause parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36466395/sequelize-optional-where-clause-parameters)

but this answer doesn't work anymore. I also tried another way of building the where clause, but I failed on it as well (mainly due to sequelize operators).
The last thing I tried was to make a single query with all parameters included but try to find some value (or flag) that would make sequelize ignore the parameter, for the case when the parameter was no there*, but it looks like Sequelize doesn't have anything like that.

* I've read a question here that has an answer saying that `{}` would do the trick but I tried that as well but didn't work.

In summary: I need to make a query that can "change" over time, for example:

```
Foo.findAll({
  where: { 
  id : 1,
  }
});

Foo.findAll({
  where: { 
  id {
   [Op.in] : [1,2,3,4,5]
  },
  name: "palmeiira",
  }
});
```

Do you know a way of doing it without the need of using a lot if / switch statements?

I'm currently using Sequelize v. 5.5.1.

**Update**

I tried doing as suggested by @Anatoly and created a function to build the parameters. It was something like that. (I tried a "smaller" version just to test)

```
async function test() {
  const where = {};
  where[Op.and] = [];
  where[Op.eq].push({
    id: {
    [Op.in]: [1,2,3] 
    }
  });

  return where;
}
```

I setted the return value to a const:

```
const query = await test()
```

And tried `console.log(query)`
The result was: **{ [Symbol(and)]: [ { id: [Object] } ] }**, which made me believe that the problem was parsing the `Op`  part so i tried using `'Op.and'` and `'Op.in'` to avoid that and it solved this problem, but led to another on sequelize that said **Invalid value**

Do you have any idea where is my error ?

P.S.: @Anatoly very nice idea you gave me on original answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: four `if`'s will be enough?

Comment: @Anatoly i don't think it would be enough. For this specific case i guess I'd take at least 4! = 24 ```if```'s.

I believe that instead of using ```if``` 's to add (because I can't use inside Sequelize's where), in this case each ```ìf``` should correspond to a combination of parameters that can be sent inside the request, for example:   
1. Start date and client name
2. Both dates and client name
3. Client name and employee name
..... and so go on.

Comment: ok, I'll try to show a solution in an answer

Comment: Ypu can't use an array for Op.eq just fro Op.or and Op.and

Comment: Thank you very, much, @Anatoly. With that new detail your solution worked pretty fine. However, I'd like to ask you another thing, if possible. Do you know the reason only Op.or and Op.and are accepted ? Again, thank you very much.

Comment: I suppose it's by design. AND and OR conditions expects there will be more then one condition on the other hands Op.eq relays on equality to a certain single value. In case you have several values you can always use Op.in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If these three conditions should work together then you can use **Op.and** with an array of conditions:

```
const where = {}

if (datesFilter || clientNameFilter || employeenameFilter) {
  where[Op.and] = []
  if (datesFilter) {
    where[Op.and].push({
      dateField: {
        [Op.between]: [datesFilter.start, datesFilter.finish]
      }
    })
  }
  if (clientNameFilter) {
    where[Op.and].push({
      name: {
        [Op.iLike]: `%${clientNameFilter.value}%`
      }
    })
  }
  if (employeenameFilter) {
    where[Op.and].push({
      employeeName: {
        [Op.iLike]: `%${employeenameFilter.value}%`
      }
    })
  }
}

const dashboardItems = await DashboardItem.findAll({ where }, {
// some options here
})
```

If the conditions should work as alternatives then just replace **Op.and** with **Op.or**

Comment: I updated the question with the problem I'm having now that I tried your solution. Do you have any idea what might be causing it ? Thank you for your answer. @Anatoly

Comment: `DashboardItem.findAll(where,...` should be `DashboardItem.findAll({where: where}, ...`

Comment: @palmeiira You should replace ` where[Op.eq]` with ` where[Op.and]`